# How to show the transition in highchart series graph without refreshing the html webpage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, highcharts

I am getting JSON data using an api which is being stored in an data.json file.
Later a javascript is using that data.json file and using it to draw highcharts. The JSON File is changing every instant and the data.json file is getting update with the data.I am linking this javascript file to an html file and later running it on chrome browser. As data.json file is changing every instant then the graph corresponding to it is also changing every instant. In order to see the graphs I have to manually refresh to see that graph . How do I show the transitions in the data in the graphs without refreshing the browser.

I DONOT WANT TO REFRESH THE DIV OR EITHER THE ENTIRE HTML PAGE something dynamically. 
Reference: https://onedesigncompany.com/

Similar to the transitions in this website.
This is how my [graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EFV30.png) looks like
This is my html + javascript code

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
enter code here<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.6.0/underscore.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; max-width: 800px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">





$(document).ready(function() {
   
    $("#container").load("index.html");



    var options = {
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'scatter',
            zoomType: 'xy'
        },
         title: {
            text: 'Number of people Versus floor'
        },
        xAxis: {
            title: {
                enabled: true,
                text: 'Uids'
            },
            startOnTick: true,
            endOnTick: true,
            showLastLabel: true
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Floor'
            }
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'left',
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            x: 100,
            y: 70,
            floating: true,
            backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColor) || '#FFFFFF',
            borderWidth: 1
        },
        
        plotOptions: {
            scatter: {
                    marker: {
                        radius: 5,
                        states: {
                            hover: {
                                enabled: true,
                                lineColor: 'rgb(100,100,100)'
                            }
                        }
                    },
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        marker: {
                            enabled: false
                        }
                    }
                },
                tooltip: {
                    headerFormat: '<b>{series.name}</b><br>',
                    pointFormat: 'uid: {point.x} , floor: {point.y} '
                }
            }
    },


        
//        series: [{}]
        
    };


    $.getJSON('/static/data/data.json', function(data) {
        
        //floor0 data
    var floor0=[];
    var i,j;
    for(i=0;i<data.size;i++)
    {
        if(data.occupancy_information[i].building=="Academic" && data.occupancy_information[i].floor=="0")
            floor0.push(data.occupancy_information[i].uids);
    }
    var merged0 = [].concat.apply([], floor0);
    var result0=[];
    result0=merged0.map(Number);    
    var len0=result0.length;
    
    var iMax0 = len0;
    var jMax0 = 2;
    var f0 = new Array();


     for (i=0;i<iMax0;i++) {
     f0[i]=new Array();
     for (j=0;j<jMax0;j++) {
      f0[i][0]=parseInt(merged0[i]);
      f0[i][1]=0;

     }
    }
        
        
        //floor1 data    
    var floor1=[];
    for(i=0;i<data.size;i++)
    {
        if(data.occupancy_information[i].building=="Academic" && data.occupancy_information[i].floor=="1")
            floor1.push(data.occupancy_information[i].uids);
    }
    var merged1 = [].concat.apply([], floor1);
    var result1=[];
    result1=merged1.map(Number);    
    var len1=result1.length;
    
    var iMax1 = len1;
    var jMax1 = 2;
    var f1 = new Array();


     for (i=0;i<iMax1;i++) {
     f1[i]=new Array();
     for (j=0;j<jMax1;j++) {
      f1[i][0]=parseInt(merged1[i]);
      f1[i][1]=1;

     }
    }
       
        
             //floor2 data    
    var floor2=[];
    for(i=0;i<data.size;i++)
    {
        if(data.occupancy_information[i].building=="Academic" && data.occupancy_information[i].floor=="2")
            floor2.push(data.occupancy_information[i].uids);
    }
    var merged2 = [].concat.apply([], floor2);
    var result2=[];
    result2=merged2.map(Number);    
    var len2=result2.length;
    
    var iMax2 = len2;
    var jMax2 = 2;
    var f2 = new Array();


     for (i=0;i<iMax2;i++) {
     f2[i]=new Array();
     for (j=0;j<jMax2;j++) {
      f2[i][0]=parseInt(merged2[i]);
      f2[i][1]=2;

     }
    }
        
            //floor3 data    
    var floor3=[];
    for(i=0;i<data.size;i++)
    {
        if(data.occupancy_information[i].building=="Academic" && data.occupancy_information[i].floor=="3")
            floor3.push(data.occupancy_information[i].uids);
    }
    var merged3 = [].concat.apply([], floor3);
    var result3=[];
    result3=merged3.map(Number);    
    var len3=result3.length;
    
    var iMax3 = len3;
    var jMax3 = 2;
    var f3 = new Array();


     for (i=0;i<iMax3;i++) {
     f3[i]=new Array();
     for (j=0;j<jMax3;j++) {
      f3[i][0]=parseInt(merged3[i]);
      f3[i][1]=3;

     }
    }

            //floor4 data    
    var floor4=[];
    for(i=0;i<data.size;i++)
    {
        if(data.occupancy_information[i].building=="Academic" && data.occupancy_information[i].floor=="4")
            floor4.push(data.occupancy_information[i].uids);
    }
    var merged4 = [].concat.apply([], floor4);
    var result4=[];
    result4=merged4.map(Number);    
    var len4=result4.length;
    
    var iMax4 = len4;
    var jMax4 = 2;
    var f4 = new Array();


     for (i=0;i<iMax4;i++) {
     f4[i]=new Array();
     for (j=0;j<jMax4;j++) {
      f4[i][0]=parseInt(merged4[i]);
      f4[i][1]=4;

     }
    }
        
        //floor5 data    
    var floor5=[];
    for(i=0;i<data.size;i++)
    {
        if(data.occupancy_information[i].building=="Academic" && data.occupancy_information[i].floor=="5")
            floor5.push(data.occupancy_information[i].uids);
    }
    var merged5 = [].concat.apply([], floor5);
    var result5=[];
    result5=merged5.map(Number);    
    var len5=result5.length;
    
    var iMax5 = len5;
    var jMax5 = 2;
    var f5 = new Array();


     for (i=0;i<iMax5;i++) {
     f5[i]=new Array();
     for (j=0;j<jMax5;j++) {
      f5[i][0]=parseInt(merged5[i]);
      f5[i][1]=5;

     }
    }
                   
        var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
        chart.addSeries({                        
            name: 'Ground floor',
            data: f0
        }, false);
        chart.addSeries({                        
            name: 'First Floor',
            data: f1
        }, false);
         chart.addSeries({                        
            name: 'Second Floor',
            data: f2
        }, false);
         chart.addSeries({                        
            name: 'Third Floor',
            data: f3
        }, false);
         chart.addSeries({                        
            name: 'Fourth Floor',
            data: f4
        }, false);
        chart.addSeries({                        
            name: 'Fifth Floor',
            data: f5
        }, false);
        chart.redraw();

    });

});

</script>
```

Comment: By "changing every instant" do you mean the entire data set is altered or that a new data point is added?

Comment: Have you looked at the demos?  http://www.highcharts.com/demo/dynamic-update

Comment: The entire data.json file changes as as the apidata changes at every instant.

Comment: Can you provide a sample data set representative of your formatting?

Comment: @wergeld : I have added both the graph image and the code.

Comment: @jlbriggs : Mine is a scatter graph . would it be applicable on scatters plots too?

Comment: the concept is the same no matter what you're plotting. specific behavior may vary, of course.

Comment: If you're updating the entire data set instead of just adding a point, then instead of series.addPoint() as used in the demo, you would use series.setData() - http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.setData

Answer (score 2):

Keep your ajax /getJson in the set interval and pass the data to your massager function when it returns data every five seconds, this way the page doesn't get refreshed.

Look at this example

```
var time_interval = 5000;
setInterval(function () {
$.ajax({
    url: 'your_path_to_the_api',
    data: '',
    cache: false,
    type: 'POST',
    success: function (data) {
        $('#container').text(data);
      }
   });
 }, time_interval);
```

Comment: the reason I switched to flask was because this gives me CORS error which I am unable to resolve.
This would fetch the data after every 5 seconds , which my python file is already doing.
the problem is reflecting the changes in the html file when run on the web browser.

mere adding of this line refreshes my html page and update the graph according to that particular data instant. 
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10" />

But then the transitions are not smooth.
Which fails my purpose

Comment: Did you try making independent ajax calls and then getting this data?

Answer (score 0):

You want to update chart, when your data in the backend is updated. To achieve that you have two ways:

- as the other answer states, use AJAX with `setInterval`, where you will request new data from the backend. The problem is that, your data may be not updated yet, or updated before, so you may miss/late with the graph update.
- use websockets (or long polling) with database which will have publish possibility (like Redis). Then create websocket connection between backend and frontend. When connection is set, your database should emit signal that "new data is available" and in the backend gather all new data and send via websocket to the front end, and in front end update data using `chart.series[index].setData(new_data)`.

The second solution of course requires backend: database and server. If this is too much, then you need to use the first one.

You can also consider using some platform which implements natively second solution. For example [Meteor](https://www.meteor.com/).

Answer (score -1):

Why not set a time interval so that it refreshes every 5 seconds?
http://devzone.co.in/automatically-refresh-html-page-div-specific-time-interval/